# How to reach code inside a subscription of an observable property of a datasource

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

How can I test (reach) this code?

```
 selection = new SelectionModel<ContractList>(true, []);

 constructor(private contractListFacade: ContractListFacade) {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource = new ListDataSource(this.contractListFacade);
    this.dataSource.reset();
    this.dataSource.loadContractListCollection();

    this.subscription.add(
      this.dataSource.loading$.subscribe((loadingState: LoadingState) => this.loading = loadingState)
    );
    
    this.subscription.add(
      this.dataSource.contracts$.subscribe((contractListCollection: ContractList[]) => {     
        this.selection.clear();

        // I want to reach this part
        contractListCollection.forEach((contractList: ContractList) => this.selection.select(contractList));                              
        // but I dont know how to do

      })      
    );
  }
```

Trying to set a spyOn(component.dataSource.contract$, 'subscribe') but its not even called.

```
it('should select all data rows from datasource.contracts$', () => { 
    const mockValues = values();        
    component.dataSource.contracts$ = of(mockValues);
    
    const spy = spyOn(component.dataSource.contracts$, 'subscribe');
    component.ngOnInit();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

The method values() return some test data. In the end I would like to have something like

```
const spySelect = spyOn(component.selection, 'select');
expect(spySelect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(mockValues.length);
expect(component.selection.selected.length).toEqual(mockValues.length);
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If ListDataSource isn't a dependency, you shouldn't be changing its value, I would assume you are probably reseting the contract$ you just set inside its constructor or methods that are called within ngOnInit. What you should be spying and mocking instead are values from contractListFacade that you use inside ListDataSource